# Error building rviz on osx

Tags: rviz, ros-groovy, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Building rviz on osx i have encountered another problem

[ 61%] 1 warning generated.
Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/moc_tool_properties_panel.cxx.o
Linking CXX shared library /Users/tatsch/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rviz/lib/librviz.dylib
ld: library not found for -lOgreMain
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [/Users/tatsch/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rviz/lib/librviz.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

<== Failed to process package 'rviz':
KeyboardInterrupt
Command failed, exiting.

I found in the ogre forum that this seems to be one of the usual quirks about OS X. The solution could be to use -framework Ogre instead of -lOgreMain, but where would i have to apply that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52546/error-building-rviz-on-osx/) by [J.M.T.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3816/j.m.t./) on ROS Answers with karma: 266 on 2013-01-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure you have the latest version of Ogre installed from our repo.

```
brew remove ogre
brew update
(ros/groovy/ogre should update)
brew install ogre
(or you can do rosdep again)
```

---

Originally posted by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) with karma: 1626 on 2013-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0